# Regular expression

Tags: regex

Below is my text Data from which I have to find MI, mi, MumbaiIndians, MUMBAIINDIANS words through regex.

```
HATHWAY / MBBS : [PM1-PTY-PM / MUMBAIINDIANS0/2/2] || WICKET DOWN 
HATHWAY / MBBS : [PM1-PTY-PM /MUMBAIINDIANS0/2/2] || WICKET DOWN
HATHWAY / MBBS : [PM1-PTY-PM / MI0/2/2] || WICKET DOWN
HATHWAY / MBBS : [PM1-PTY-PM /MI0/2/2] || WICKET DOWN
HATHWAY / MBBS : [PM1-PTY-PM /MI ] || WICKET DOWN
HATHWAY / MBBS : [PM1-PTY-PM / mi0/2/2] || WICKET DOWN 
HATHWAY / MBBS : [PM1-PTY-PM / MumbaiINDIANS0/2/2] || WICKET DOWN
HATHWAY / MBBS : [PM1-PTY-PM /Me ] || WICKET DOWN
```

I wrote regex query for this as below

```
`/((\bMi[^0-9-!\s$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/]*)|(MI[^0-9-!\s$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/]*)|(\bMi[^0-9-!\s$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/]*)|(MumbaiINDIANS[^0-9-!\s$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/]*)|(\bMi[^0-9-!\s$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/]*)|(mi[^0-9-!\s$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/]*))/`
```

It is working but It is not efficient and looks very complex ... what I want is MI, mi, me, MumbaiIndians , MUMBAIINDIANS words to words to gets selected irrespective of their locations.

Please anyone tell me how to optimize this query.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem with regex which is best suitable for tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might shorten your pattern to (using a case insensitive match)

To prevent a partial match, you could use an assertion to make sure that it is not followed by a char a-zA-Z using a negative lookahead `(?!`

```
(?i)\b(?:mumbaiindians|mi)(?![A-Za-z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/owsMF9/1)

Or you can assert one of the listed chars to the right using a positive lookahead `(?=`

```
(?i)\b(?:mumbaiindians|mi)(?=[0-9-!\s$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HVkqtp/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ig` for *insensitive, global* with a positive lookbehind / lookahead:

```regex
/(?<=[\d \/])mumbaiindians|mi|me(?=[\d \/])/ig
```

[Regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/7OVOYn/1)